# getArrayResult on entity with ManyToOne association

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Having the follow basic tables  (one-to-many relationship)
Client   - Has many users.
Users   - Each user belongs to single client.

In a very simple example if I query the user entity (Querybuilder)
with `getArrayResult()` I see the following:

1. The actual generated SQL contains the foreign key field to be
   returned (i.e. ClientID)
2. The actual returned data array does NOT contain the foreign key
   field.

At this stage I do not need to return foreign data and so do not need
to join to the associated table.

So question is...
What or how do I return the foreign key value in my array?

Query is:

```
   $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();  
   $qb->select('e');  
   $qb->from('Entity\User', 'e');
```

SQL is:

```
SELECT w0_.Id AS Id0, w0_.Name AS Name2, w0_.ClientID AS ClientID7
FROM users w0_
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to set the `HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS` query hint on the query (not the builder) before you execute it.

```
$q->setHint(Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true);
```

Comment: Will this not work if I try and grab just the foreign key field in the select statement (as opposed to the whole entity)? It doesn't seem to be for me.

Comment: Great, this one's a lifesaver!

Comment: thank you, now i am a step forward, but i need relations as array not just id... to be able to process it with json with one request and not 10 requests for each id here

Comment: This is interesting, but doesn't work quite as expected.
Getting the foreign key seems normal to me, but for some reason the associated column names are returned in snake_case, whereas the other properties are returned in CamelCase.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do this, because ClientID is not a property of User.  User has a property like $client, and that client entity has an $id.

This is confusing you because you're dealing with Entites but you're still thinking in SQL.

The solution, though slightly less efficient, would probably be to join the Client entity into your DQL query, and then get `$results[N]['client']['id']` (or similar, I'm not too familiar with getResultArray())

Comment: This is the solution that I was using, and appreciate that I should be thinking 'entities and ORM', not SQL... but we still want efficient SQL being generated. We really don't want to join to another table unnecessarily. Very inefficient. Thanks for the comment though...