# Get parent_id of Gedmo Tree element using symfony3, doctrine2 and stofDoctrineExtensionsBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, tree, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

### Introduction

I am using Symfony v3.1.6, Doctrine v2.5.4 and StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle [1] in order to manage Tree structure.

To setup Tree structure I used documentation on Symfony.com [2] followed by documentation on GitHub [3]. Then I proceeded with tree setup - used tree entity from example [4] and used code in [5] to create a tree.

- [1] [stofDoctrineExtensionsBundle on GitHub](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle);
- [2] [stofDoctrineExtensinsBundnle documentation on Symfony.com](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html);
- [3] [Gedmo Tree documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md);
- [4] [Gedmo Tree > Tree Entity example](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#tree-entity-example);
- [5] [Gedmo Tree > Basic Usage Example](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#basic-usage-examples);

### Code

Function in `CategoryRepository`

```
public function getParentId($child_node_id)
{
    // get parent_id of a tree element
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('c')
        ->from('AppBundle:Category', 'c')
        ->where('c.id = :nodeId')
        ->setParameter('nodeId', $child_node_id)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery();

    $parent = $query->getResult();
    $parent_null = $parent[0]->getParent();

    // if parent element is null - efectively element is root of the tree
    if ($parent_null === null)
    {
        $parent_id = $parent[0]->getId();
    }
    // if parent element is not root of the tree
    else
    {
        $parent_id = $parent[0]->getParent()->getId();
    }

    return $parent_id;
}
```

When I use `$parent = $query->getResult()` I get following output:

```
array:1 [?
  0 => Category {#581 ?
    -id: 3
    -title: "Vegetables"
    -is_file: false
    -lft: 4
    -lvl: 1
    -rgt: 11
    -root: Category {#518 ?}
    -parent: Category {#518 ?
      -id: 1
      -title: "Food"
      -is_file: false
      -lft: 1
      -lvl: 0
      -rgt: 12
      -root: Category {#518}
      -parent: null
      -children:
```

but when I use `$parent = $query->getArrayResult()` I get:

```
array:1 [?
  0 => array:6 [?
    "id" => 2
    "title" => "Fruits"
    "is_file" => false
    "lft" => 2
    "lvl" => 1
    "rgt" => 3
  ]
]
```

Note that there is no parent_id in the `getArrayResult` output...

### Question

So the question is - how can one get tree node `parent_id` in the query result with `getArrayResult` ?

### Conclusion

Please advise.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out one has to hint to get all the related values when using `getArrayResult`.

Vanilla answer [1] did not work for me, so I made little modification (full path to Query).

`$query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true);`

Note, that hinting is going on on the `$query` and is placed between query and getting the result.

Links:

1. [Found initial info here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5485893/3137047)
2. [Documentation on hints](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-hints)